# Way of expressing transcendental number in terms of known mathematical constants?

Tags: pi, math-software, transcendental-numbers

During my research I found a constant which is a transcendental number and I am able to calculate it to high precision (like 300 and more decimal places).

Do you know of a computer/online program, mathematical way or anything where I might be able to find an expression for such a number in terms of known constants, e.g. pi, e, etc?

Comment: http://oeis.org/ might help

Comment: A complex number $z$ can be tested to see if it is transcendental using the Wolfram Language command *Not[Element[x, Algebraics]]*:
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TranscendentalNumber.html

Comment: Is the "inverse symbolic calculator" of Simon Plouffe still online? - Just try with google... Ah, and Robert Munafo (website "big numbers" or so) has a similar thing, but following a different philosophy to point to combinations of other constants (I didn't manage to use it properly so I didn't bookmark, sorry).

Comment: wolfram alpha gives you a list of possible closed forms, but do not expect that every thinkable expression is found.